# Why do demons imply I'm weak when I ask for a card?

Tags: smt-persona

In *Shin Megami Tensei: Persona*, when I get the option to obtain a spell card, some demons say I'm being cocky or something and I should get stronger first. The thing is, one demon was level 21 and Maki (who was talking to the demon) was Level 23 and had a Persona Level of 23, yet the demon still said I needed to get stronger.

What is it I'm missing that makes demons think I'm weak?

Comment: It is probably just bad AI, I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: @Johann i don't think so, it was working fine at the beginning of the game but i've been unsuccessful since i transferred to the other world and you have to negotiate with demons to get spell cards to created more powerful persona's, and it's not just 1 demon, every demon i've came across has said it, i only been able to create 2 new persona's, one so far doesn't have a single offensive spell (but she absorbs elements so she's good in her own way)

Comment: was he talking about the party in general or just maki

Comment: @Johann not sure, if it was just Maki then it would make sense cause she's the strongest in the party with a higher level then most because she tends to kill more enemies thanks to her original Persona's attacks, also, as i mentioned in the question, in the instance i explained Maki was 2 levels higher with bother her own level and her Persona Level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found out that the reason is because of my party's average level, it seems it must be higher then the level of the monster your negotiating with

after learning this i've had to start a new game cause Maki is now like 9 levels higher than anyone else messing up the average and am now trying to keep there levels around the same